# How to skip one column using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image: Design for the grid system]

I need to keep the middle grid-item empty. I thought it would have been possible with the following property: `grid-template-areas`

```
grid-template-areas:
  "header . header"
  "main . ."
  "footer . footer";
```

But this unfortunately does not give the correct display.

So I did it with 5 classes named item-a to item-e and then in css set the correct position in the grid. This however doesn't feel like a very efficient way to do it. Does any one know how to make it a more efficient?

```css
.content-container {
    width: 51.5em;
    height: 30em;
    padding: 2.125em 1.5em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 45% auto 45%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }

  .item-a {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
  }

  .item-b {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
  }

  .item-c {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }

  .item-d {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3 / 3;
  }

  .item-e {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3 / 3;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="item-a">
    <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your first name">
  </div>
  <div class="item-b">
    <label for="lastName" class="label">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>
  <div class="item-c">
    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
  <div class="item-d">
    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password">
  </div>
  <div class="item-e">
    <label for="passwordConfirmation" class="label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password again">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need all that code, you can simplify like below:

```css
.content-container {
  max-width: 51.5em;
  height: 20em;
  padding: 2.125em 1.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* define only 2 columns*/
  column-gap: 4em; /* control the gap between both columns*/
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item-d {
  grid-column: 1; /* move the passwer to the first column instead of the second one*/
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your first name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName" class="label">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
  <div class="item-d">
    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordConfirmation" class="label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password again">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another simplification:

```css
.content-container {
  max-width: 51.5em;
  height: 20em;
  padding: 2.125em 1.5em;
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 4em;
  border:1px solid;
}

.content-container :nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row:span 2;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your first name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName" class="label">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
  <div >
    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordConfirmation" class="label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password again">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to do this with the `grid-template-areas` property?

Comment: @Ezrab_ yes but not needed for a simple layout like this. The auto placement will do 90% of the job for you, you only need one instruction to move one element

Comment: thanks! But I'm trying to learn how grid works by creating this same grid in different ways. That's why I want to know how would one would do it.

Comment: @Ezrab_ always start by having your grid place the items for you then adjust when it's needed. If you start by placing yourself all the elements, you will be lost and it won't be efficient especially when the layout is easy.

Comment: How to set 100% width for these field?

Answer (score 1):

Though it's technically not "skipping" a column, you can alternatively just use an empty element, such as a `div`, with a minuscule `width`/`height`, essentially as a placeholder, to have an "empty" space while maintaining the grid flow.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item-full{
    grid-column: 1/-1
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="content-container">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your first name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName" class="label">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>
  <div class="item-full">
    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
  <div class="item-d">
    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordConfirmation" class="label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password again">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have other solution because in that case that we can choose **exact field** can be selected and that field also have the full size.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.content-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item-full{
    grid-column: 1/-1
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-container">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your first name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName" class="label">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>
  <div class="item-full">
    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
  <div class="item-d">
    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordConfirmation" class="label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter your password again">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```